# How to make sure changes to a Wordpress plugin won't be lost on plugin update?

Tags: wordpress

I'm pretty sure I've read somewhere that you can actually move the main plugin *.php file to somewhere else (I assume under your theme directory) to have it safe in case you made changes to it and your plugin updates. I tried Google but I can't find anything. Google page with good results will suffice.

I've just experienced a situation where my 2 plugins which had its layout changed and accommodated my needs and I want to make sure it doesn't happen again. Apart from having the main file in another location, is there a way to move along any CSS and JS files as well?

In Concrete5 CMS there is a nice way of doing this, by creating a new folder inside a block of an addon (may be regarded as a WP plugin), inside of which you can create copies of main file, any CSS and JS files and then you can simply edit them and choose that template for a page location you are using that block in.

I assume there is no such thing in Wordpress but how close can I get?

UPDATE: I found where I applied that advice on creating a new instance of the file then moving it to the theme directory.
The plugin in question was HL-Twitter. These are the plugin files:

```
admin.php
archive.php
functions.php
hl_twitter.php
hl_twitter_archive.php
hl_twitter_widget.php
import.php
widget.php
```

Now, this is the top contents (commented out) of the hl_twitter_widget.php:

```
Widget Theme for HL Twitter
To change this theme, copy hl_twitter_widget.php
to your current theme folder, do not edit this
file directly.

Available Properties:
$before_widget
$after_widget
$before_title
$after_title
$widget_title
$show_avatars
$show_powered_by
$num_tweets: how many tweets to show
$tweets: array of $tweet
$tweet: object representing a tweet
$tweet->twitter_tweet_id
$tweet->tweet
$tweet->lat
$tweet->lon
$tweet->created
$tweet->reply_tweet_id
$tweet->reply_screen_name
$tweet->source
$tweet->screen_name
$tweet->name
$tweet->avatar
$user: represents the Twitter user (ONLY SET IF SHOWING A SINGLE USERS TWEETS!)
$user->twitter_user_id
$user->screen_name
$user->name
$user->num_friends
$user->num_followers
$user->num_tweets
$user->registered
$user->url
$user->description
$user->location
$user->avatar
```

So I was wrong about copying the main file (in this case hl_twitter.php), but still - this enabled me to edit the file outside the plugin directory and the system somehow checks for its existence and picks it up if exists.
If this behavior something that is natively supported by Wordpress or it has been integrated in the plugin itself?

Comment: You're likely to enter a world of pain with this, as there is no coding standard for WP plugins. You'll have to do a diff between the old and the new version on every update, there's no better way to do it... that's why it's not a good idea to edit 3rd party plugins. (Of course, you can simply copy the entire plugin directory after every change to make sure, but plugins can change completely and without notice)

Comment: I'd be happy if I'm at least able to make a new instance of the main file and then edit that file, not the one at the original location.

Comment: you mean just inside Wordpress, without any help from a FTP program? There might be a plugin for that, but maybe it's easier for you to do from your web host's control panel?

Comment: The issue here is not on moving part itself. I can move it with no problems but I need to know where I can move it so it still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With themes, Wordpress has a concept of "child themes" which allows exactly that: to keep changes separate from main theme, in case it changes.

I haven't yet found a way to do this with plugins.

I'm using a few tactics myself:

- I bump plugin version to a very high number like 99.9. This way Wordpress won't ever update the plugin.
- Store my plugins in version control (i use git, but it doesnt matter), this allows you to update the plugin, run the 'diff' tool and see what changes happend. If you don't like you just revert like it would be a bad code you've written. But this approach requires a bit of skill.

Comment: So you haven't heard of the possibilty for moving main plugin .php file to another location (actually, moving an instance of it)? I can't remember where I read that is possible.

Comment: Looking around a bit more: if your plugin supports _hooks_ or _filters_ you can modify them in your theme's functions.php. Very much like in child themes. But the plugin has to support that.

Comment: To protect a modified plugin from auto upgrade, it's sufficient to create a source code folder inside the plugin folder.  For instance:
`mkdir wp-content/plugins/your-modified-plugin/.hg`

Comment: Genius. Is this document somewhere? Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about running parts of a modified 3rd party plugin, and an updated version, at the same time?

That's not going to be possible. There is no magical method of "preserve my changes and transfer them into the new version automatically". The way to go here is doing a diff between the edited version and the update, and integrating the changes in the actual source files.

The bottom line is, if you manually edit a third party plugin, you're in for manual review (and possibly rework) once an update takes place. That's why it's usually not a good idea to extensively modify third party plugins.

Comment: Yes, something like that. To be precise, I want to change the appearance of a contact form that I created via Contact Form 7 plugin. So, no adding functions, just changing HTML and CSS styling.
I think I recently read something about taking main .php file from the plugin directory and then placing it into the (active theme??) directory. Then you can edit that file and leave the original plugin file intact, thus avoiding losses on updates.

Comment: @denny it may or may not be possible to do that, it'll depend entirely on how the plugin is structured. If the HTML and CSS are in separate files, you may be able to back those up. But you also may not - it really depends on the plugin, there are no binding rules for this

Answer (score 0):

Well in fact, yes! There is some kind of way.
You have to remove the to be modificated plugin's original actions/filters and then add your altereted actions/filters.

If the desired plugin is even coded in OOP you can just inherit the whole class and rewrite the wanted functions (oh sorry: "methods". we're talking about OOP ;) ). Instantiate your inherited class and rest as above.

Maybe there are better ways! I already search for a method so that the original class won't even get loaded but our altered one instead but I'm no John Carmack.