# Contact form 7 adding custom attribute to input text

Tags: wordpress, list, text, attributes, contact-form-7

I needed to add datalist-support on contact form 7 (version 3.8) text-field.
See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

---

After searching the web without according results I extended the preset pattern for the get_option-function in 
/plugins/contact-form-7/**includes/shortcodes.php**
with the list-pattern (line 249). Last line of the following code:

```
$preset_patterns = array(
  'date' => '([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|today(.*))',
  'int' => '[0-9]+',
  'signed_int' => '-?[0-9]+',
  'class' => '[-0-9a-zA-Z_]+',
  'id' => '[-0-9a-zA-Z_]+',
  'list' => '[-0-9a-zA-Z_]+' );
```

and added the list-attribute (line 49) in the text-module 
/plugins/contact-form-7/**modules/text.php**

```
$atts['list'] = $tag->get_option( 'list', 'list', true );
```

---

That solution is actually working. But only until the next update is applied.

Is there a better solution to this problem? (Prior to that change I used an input-text together with a select-box.)

Any hint, help or comment appreciated.

Comment: ok, found a related thread to this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960212/how-to-make-sure-changes-to-a-wordpress-plugin-wont-be-lost-on-plugin-update

Comment: This [page](https://www.lockedownseo.com/add-name-attribute-to-contact-form-7/) indicates how to add attributes to a Contact Form 7 form within the form's definition. This means it should be impervious to updates, & no code needs be written. [CF7 docs](https://contactform7.com/faq/can-i-add-id-and-class-attributes-to-a-form-element/) seems add credibility to that method. I have not tried it myself, but it's part of my (eventual) todo list, for adding auto-complete type attributes to some form fields. IF someone tries this before I do, feel free to leave feedback. I'd like to know how it goes.